# SLURM script for running RSEM star fails

Tags: star, rsem, slurm

If you have worked on cluster with submitting jobs, please help me in resolving the following error.

I am running rsem pipeline to generate star index. In principal STAR requires more than 30G of RAM for human genome.

I have following script

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --mail-user=<your_email_address>
#SBATCH --mail-type=end,fail
#SBATCH --job-name="job01"
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=10G

rsem-prepare-reference --gtf ~/Genomes/Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.100.chr.gtf -p 5 --star --star-path ~/Tools/STAR/bin/Linux_x86_64/ ~/Genomes/Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.toplevel.fa ~/Genomes/GRCh38_100
```

The process fails as soon as it starts to generate genome files using star. Below is the error complaining about the memory.

I have put 5 threads for star usage and 10G for each cpu.

here is the error

```
rsem-preref /storage/homefs/as21u994/Genomes/GRCh38_100.transcripts.fa 1 /storage/homefs/as21u994/Genomes/GRCh38_100
Refs.makeRefs finished!
Refs.saveRefs finished!
/storage/homefs/as21u994/Genomes/GRCh38_100.idx.fa is generated!
/storage/homefs/as21u994/Genomes/GRCh38_100.n2g.idx.fa is generated!

/storage/homefs/as21u994/Tools/STAR/bin/Linux_x86_64//STAR  --runThreadN 8  --runMode genomeGenerate  --genomeDir /storage/homefs/as21u994/Genomes  --genomeFastaFiles /storage/homefs/as21u994/Genomes/Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.toplevel.fa  --sjdbGTFfile /storage/homefs/as21u994/Genomes/Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.100.chr.gtf  --sjdbOverhang 100  --outFileNamePrefix /storage/homefs/as21u994/Genomes/GRCh38_100
Feb 25 12:10:58 ..... started STAR run
Feb 25 12:10:58 ... starting to generate Genome files

EXITING because of FATAL PARAMETER ERROR: limitGenomeGenerateRAM=31000000000is too small for your genome
SOLUTION: please specify --limitGenomeGenerateRAM not less than 168632691637 and make that much RAM available

Feb 25 12:18:11 ...... FATAL ERROR, exiting
"/storage/homefs/as21u994/Tools/STAR/bin/Linux_x86_64//STAR  --runThreadN 8  --runMode genomeGenerate  --genomeDir /storage/homefs/as21u994/Genomes  --genomeFastaFiles /storage/homefs/as21u994/Genomes/Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.toplevel.fa  --sjdbGTFfile /storage/homefs/as21u994/Genomes/Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.100.chr.gtf  --sjdbOverhang 100  --outFileNamePrefix /storage/homefs/as21u994/Genomes/GRCh38_100" failed! Plase check if you provide correct parameters/options for the pipeline!
```

Could anyone of you tell me how to fix this.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried allocating more than 10GB of RAM? It seems like the error is related to memory..

Comment: I have tried till 50G. Don't know what is happening

Comment: Try to use the `--mem=` parameter to allocate a fixed amount of memory for the entire job, not mem per cpu. Your cluster probably has a default for that value which is probably too small for the job. For this either consult the cluster documentation or the admins.

Comment: Users have reported similar issues to STAR before: https://github.com/alexdobin/STAR/issues/129